How to Specify return_dtype for Aggregation and Sorting in Polars LazyFrame?
Let's assume I have a Polars LazyFrame or DataFrame.
In the first step, I execute a with_columns / struct / map_elements / lambda function combination to create dict objects from the columns specified in the struct.
combined_plan = combined_plan.with_columns(
    pl.struct(['candle_dt', 'timeframe', 'time_diff_seconds', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'])
        .map_elements(lambda row: row, return_dtype=pl.Object).alias('event')
)

In the second step, I perform an aggregation on the result using group_by / agg / col / map_elements, which generates lists of the dict objects created in the first step, based on a column that hasn't been used yet.
combined_plan = combined_plan.group_by('event_trigger_dt').agg(
    pl.col("event").map_elements(lambda row: row.to_list(), return_dtype=pl.List(pl.Object)).alias('events')
)

How can I specify the return_dtype so that I can perform a sorting operation without any error on the resulting frame after the aggregation?
combined_plan = combined_plan.sort(['event_trigger_dt'])

The error I get:
pyo3_runtime.PanicException: called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ComputeError(ErrString("ListArray's child's DataType must match. However, the expected DataType is FixedSizeBinary(8) while it got Extension(\"POLARS_EXTENSION_TYPE\", FixedSizeBinary(8), Some(\"1732551860809866900;4003949774752\"))."))

I've tried to use multiple types: pl.Object, pl.Struct, pl.List(pl.Object) etc., none of them worked.
I could workaround this with converting the dict into JSON and using pl.String type, but I don't like the fact that I need to convert it back to python dict where I need to use it:
def func(row):
    return {
        'candle_dt'         : str(row['candle_dt']),
        'timeframe'         : row['timeframe'],
        'time_diff_seconds' : row['time_diff_seconds'],
        'open'              : row['open'],
        'high'              : row['high'],
        'low'               : row['low'],
        'close'             : row['close'],
        'volume'            : row['volume'],
    }

combined_plan = combined_plan.with_columns(
    pl.struct(['candle_dt', 'timeframe', 'time_diff_seconds', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'])
        .map_elements(lambda row:func(row), return_dtype=pl.Object).alias('event')
)
combined_plan = combined_plan.group_by('event_trigger_dt').agg(
    pl.col("event").map_elements(lambda row: str(json.dumps(row.to_list())), return_dtype=pl.String).alias('events')
)
combined_plan = combined_plan.sort(['event_trigger_dt'])


You cannot create List(Object): https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/18591#issuecomment-2336594359 - Is there a specific reason why you are using the Object type at all?

The point here is not to insist to the Object type, but make the sort function work with dict type. I'll be happy to replace the Object type there if you can show me a working solution.

I don't think Polars currently allows you to sort list[struct] pl.DataFrame({"a": [[{"x": 1}]]}).sort(pl.all()) gives InvalidOperationError
